# Realloc into a function

Tags: c, function, initialization, realloc

My question is about `realloc`.

The following code works correctly (with no warning):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int num=10;
    int *vet;
    int i;

        for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        /* allocate memory of vet to contains (i+1) int */
        vet = (int*) realloc ( vet, (i+1) * sizeof(int) );
    
        /* write numbers in the allocated memory */
        vet[i] = 321 + i;
    }

    /* print test, if all works I must see:
    | 321 | 322 | 323 | 324 | 325 | 326 | 327 | 328 | 329 | 330 | */
    printf ("| ");
    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
        printf ("%d | ", vet[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

But the same program with a function doesn't work! And the compiler return the following warning:

```
In function ‘main’:
14:10: warning: ‘vet’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void memoria (int *, int);

int main ()
{
    int *vet, num=10;

    memoria (vet, num);

    /* print test, if all works I must see:
    | 321 | 322 | 323 | 324 | 325 | 326 | 327 | 328 | 329 | 330 | */
    int i;
    printf ("| ");
    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
        printf ("%d | ", vet[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}

void memoria (int *vet, int num)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        /* allocate memory of vet to contains (i+1) int */
        vet = (int*) realloc ( vet, (i+1) * sizeof(int) );
    
        /* write numbers in the allocated memory */
        vet[i] = 321 + i;
    }
}
```

Someone can say me why? Thank you very much!

Oh, and the same code with a 'random' malloc in main works (with the function)...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void memoria (int *, int);

int main ()
{
    int *vet, num=10;

    /* ADDED MALLOC */
    vet = (int*) malloc (1);

    memoria (vet, num);

    /* print test, if all works I must see:
    | 321 | 322 | 323 | 324 | 325 | 326 | 327 | 328 | 329 | 330 | */
    int i;
    printf ("| ");
    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
        printf ("%d | ", vet[i]);
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}

void memoria (int *vet, int num)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        /* allocate memory of vet to contains (i+1) int */
        vet = (int*) realloc ( vet, (i+1) * sizeof(int) );
    
        /* write numbers in the allocated memory */
        vet[i] = 321 + i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your function to accept int **vet and then call `memoria(&vet, num); ` from main. Also don't cast the result of malloc or realloc as it can silence valuable diagnostics, also it just looks bad.

Comment: But the vector name is already a pointer to its first element! Right?

Comment: _The following code works correctly (with no warning):_ first code `‘vet’ is used uninitialized` too.

Comment: With `gcc version 4.8.1` there are no warning (tested now)!

Comment: @user malloc and realloc give a new pointer, so your function must be able to change where the "first element" starts

Comment: Which compiler options did you use?  By default, GCC let's through archaic C code.  You should be using options like `gcc -std=c11 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror` (they're what I use almost all the time, when not needing to test for C89 or C99 compilability).  I sometimes add some extra warnings to that lot, too, but it is a good base level.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I use only `gcc -o -Wall`  ...

Comment: Some warnings, such as unused variables, are only generated when the optimizer is used.  It doesn't have to be `-O3`, but you do need some form of `-O` on the command line.

Comment: Then I must use `gcc -o -Wall -O` ?

Comment: @user Use `gcc -O -Wall -Wextra -Werror` btw `-o` is to say where you want the output ie `gcc -o foo.exe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you have this written:

```
int *vet, num=10;

memoria (vet, num);
```

The changes you make inside of `memoria` do not get sent back to `main`.  To understand this, just for fun change the value of `num` instead of `memoria` and then check it back in `main`.  The value in main will still be `10`.  The variables `vet` and `num` are passed by value so that they keep their original values in `main`.

The two most common ways around this are to pass the address of `vet` in so `memoria` can modify it, or return a new value for `vet`.

The first form looks like this:

```
memoria( & vet, num ) ;

void memoria (int **vet, int num)
{
  * vet= realloc( * vet, ... ) ;
```

Or, instead you can change the return type of `memoria`,

```
vet= memoria( vet, num ) ;

int * memoria( int * vet, int num)
{
  ...
  return vet ;
}
```

They both have their pros and cons.  The second form is probably easier for people who aren't pointerheads to follow.

**malloc/realloc fluke**

The reason your last example works is easy to see if you add in `printf`s to `main` and `memoria` to show the value of `vet`.  If it can, `realloc()` puts the new memory at the same location as the old pointer.  In your simple test case, the allocator has an easy time doing so, and so the memory stays at the same location.  If the code was more complex, and the call to `realloc()` moved the pointer, you'd be seeing a crash in `main` after.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! `num` is passed by value and it's ok because I don't want to change it, but `vet`? With `memoria (vet, num);` I pass to the function a pointer, right?

Comment: @user. Yes, you pass a pointer, but your function *changes* the pointer within itself (`vet = realloc(vet,...)` but does not return the modified pointer to `main()`

Comment: Thank you, now I understand! But how to solve the problem? (And why the last code I posted works?)

Comment: Thank you for the new part of the answer, _malloc/realloc fluke_.

Comment: @woolstar. And if I want to use a `scanf` into the first form function? `sscanf (buff, "%d", vet[i]);` doesn't work!

Comment: Yes, because `vet` is no longer an `int *`.

Answer (score 3):

Take care of these few problems and you are good to go.

Your `main` doesn't get back a`vet` which actually points to something. Return the `vet` back to your `main vet` somehow.

```
int *vet = NULL; //better bet for realloc() in this case
vet= memoria (vet, num);
```

Change the prototype accordingly to return a pointer and do remember to return `vet` in the definition.

```
int* memoria(int*, int);
```

Now to `realloc()`. Accoring to [ISO C](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html)

> If ptr is a `null pointer`, `realloc()` shall be equivalent to `malloc()`
>   for the specified size.
>
> If ptr does not match a pointer returned earlier by calloc(),
>   `malloc()`, or `realloc()` or if the space has previously been deallocated
>   by a call to `free()` or `realloc()`, the behavior is undefined.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! Then, for example, for a structure `struct example *e;` is the same right? And you now why the last code I posted works? Thank you!

Comment: And another question: if I want to solve the problem with a void function?

Comment: Yes. In your last snippet, *vet* is simply a pointer which refers to the memory block that you've allocated. You have passed this pointer to a function which reallocates it. realloc() returns a new pointer value, whose value *may* or *may not* be the same as the old pointer value.And your the old contents were somehow preserved !

Comment: Well, if you are going to reallocate the same memory in a *void function*, I am afraid we can't do it without dealing with some undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an uninitialised vet* to realloc. Realloc() is like free() in case it allocates entirely new memory (it free()s the old allocation). So any pointer passed to realloc() had better be a valid heap-pointer or a null-pointer.